# Is this ok to select data directly from database in Kentico?

Tags: kentico

Am using Kentico in just displaying products description and images and other data like price ...etc from Kentico DB, I used to make select query to get the data and it's working just fine but I need to know if it'll effect any other thing if I use such behavior, I know it would be better and easier if I used API's but what if I used select query directly?

**Note:** I never used any insertion or updating queries to insert or update data it's just displaying data.

As I saw in [Kentico Doc.](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K82/Managing+database+views+and+stored+procedures) using API's benefits is facilitating the displaying and making it much easier but will not affect if I use explicit query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always recommended to use the Kentico API to get this data mainly for performance/caching reasons.  There are other reasons as well for instance if you're using workflow or versioning.  If you use either one of those you have to do several joins to get the correct data vs. getting it directly from a single table.  There are very powerful API's and Macro methods which will do a lot of this for you already so I'd suggest working with those before calling the database directly.